# Which "try_files" nginx directive is best for the zero-day exploit?

Tags: nginx, php, security

So far I have been using the following in the php location of my nginx config files

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

However, I just saw in the Wordpress Codex guide that for the zero-day exploit the following should be used:

```
try_files $uri =404;
```

What are the differences between the two in terms of security?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use both, but in different locations.

The first `try_files` goes in your `location /` and handles all requests coming into the `server`. It has nothing to do with security, and is a pretty common setup.

The second `try_files` goes in the PHP `location` and prevents the attack. Note that this requires that nginx and PHP be reading the same files, on the same server.